# Java method naming conventions and overloading

Tags: java, naming-conventions, overloading

I have a service which must return person by some properties. And I see two strategies for naming these methods:

The first one:

```
getPersonById(int id)
getPersonByBirthDate(Date date)
getPersonByBirthDateAndSex(Date date,Sex sex)
getPersonByNameAndSex(String name,Sex sex)
getPersonByBirthDateAndNameAndSex(Date date,String name,Sex sex)
etc..
```

or applying overloading rules do the following:

```
getPerson(int id)
getPerson(Date date)
getPerson(Date date,Sex sex)
getPerson(String name,Sex sex)
getPerson(Date date,String name,Sex sex)
```

Which is right according to java naming convention?

Comment: both are OK by naming convetion. But, in enterprise world and by Clean Code principle, its better to use first option, since the name explains what its doing...

Comment: yeah I agree with @AdnanIsajbegovic or you can use constructor for important values for rest getter are preferred

Comment: The first one - that way the code documents itself. With the second one, you may have to ask your IDE which method is actually being called, making the code less quickly legible.

Comment: @AdnanIsajbegovic, `getPersonByBirthDateAndNameAndSex` doesn't look like clean code, does it? what about if we have to pass 5+ params?

Comment: If you have that many criterions to search by, consider using a `Query` class as parameter instead. Otherwise you could need a number of getters exponential in the number of criterions.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thats another problem... by Clean Code, you should design your code so that you have only functions with small number of parameters, up to 3 is ok... and you should apply "and" that much, so something like getPersonByBdayNameAndSex would be OK... In such way, you code looks like a story, its easy to update things and fix possible problems, possibly without looking at method implementation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Independent of the overloading question your design suffers from combinatorial API explosion: You start to introduce methods for all possible combinations of search criterions. An alternative would be to introduce a builder which collects criterions and in the end returns the person.

Example:

```
 queryPerson().byId(5).run();  
 queryPerson().byName("John").bySex(Sex.MALE).run();
 queryPerson().bySex(Sex.FEMALE).run();
```

And the service API now only has a nice `queryPerson()` method.

Comment: @fabian, good idea, changed to `queryPerson`

Answer (score 2):

Overloading is always better.
Many java-based KNOWN frameworks follow this approach.
Also, the main concept of overloading is because of condition you mentioned.

Having overloaded methods simplifies the developer's readability as no separate names have to be remembered.
Also, eclipse's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> feature would always suggest which method one wants to use.

Comment: What is a "_KNOWN framework_"?

Comment: you could provide examples from JDK (e.g. `StringBuider#append`)

Comment: @BoristheSpider ATG ("Art Technology Group"), Broadleaf Commerce, Even Java's libraries use this approach. The most "KNOWN" method "println()" is also overloaded. :)